# scroll & padding

Tags: css, css3, прокрутка, padding, margin

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с известной проблемой, но никак не могу ее решить, помогите найти хорошее решение.
В общем, имеется сайт на bootstrap простенький, при увеличении высоты страницы появляется вертикальный скрол который добавляет ширину в следствии чего страница заметно прыгает, как бы избежать этого прыжка, да и вообще может появления скрола.

Пример:

```
<div class="master">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Скрола нет:

```
.element {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Скрол есть:

```
.element {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**update:**
Страница написана на bootstrap и если просматривать ее с мобильных устройств то такой проблемы там нет

Comment: Да вроде это никто не решает, страница должна быть по центру и все. И при чем тут padding? Это же просто уменьшение ширины окна.

Comment: Вы не поняли, при появлении скрол имеет свою ширину и он отодвигает остальные элементы, что приводит к скачку

Comment: я именно так и понял

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome

Comment: Эм.. Вот уменьшение width при появлении скролла - это я понимаю. но увеличение-то как?

Comment: мм...появляется скрол и смещает элементы

Comment: overflow: overlay

Comment: к body это добавить ?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем отключать скроллбар? Высота может быть больше экрана? Сделайте скролл постоянно видимым и скачка не будет и доступ к прокрутке будет.

```
body { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: да, но нужно без постоянного скрола, лучше вообще без него, или с ним, но без увеличивающегося width

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите просто отключить скрол, он отключается так:

```
body{
 overflow-y:hidden
}
```

А в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome) есть такое решение: определяем ширину скрола и вычитаем такой marign:

```js
var checkScrollBars = function(){
    var b = $('body');
    var normalw = 0;
    var scrollw = 0;
    if(b.prop('scrollHeight')>b.height()){
        normalw = window.innerWidth;
        scrollw = normalw - b.width();
        $('.element').css({marginRight:'-'+scrollw+'px'});
    }
}

$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.element').toggleClass('big')
        checkScrollBars();
    })
    checkScrollBars();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        checkScrollBars();
    })
});
```

```css
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
.element {
    
    text-align:center;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: red;
}
.element.big {
    height: 900vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"><button>Нажмите</button></div>
```

Comment: без jquery бы, пробовал:
100vw - 100% не работает

Comment: с 100% шириной, естественно, `margin` не работает, ширина должна быть `auto`. Про jquery не понял

Comment: в первом окне вы используете $

Comment: и что? Это запрещено законом?

Comment: закон не при чем, у меня в проекте он не предусматривается просто.. а так бы да

Comment: В чем проблема? переводите код на чистый JS. Я дал вам идею, готовое решение за вами